# Is it possible to cancel Ctrl+C default action in another process' console?

Tags: c#, windows, console, ctrl

I want to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> default action (stop/close/kill) in an external console application on Windows. I have read about "`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`" and "`Console.TreatCtrlCAsInput`" but none of them seem to be valid for an external process.

Is there some alternative? Am I ignoring some detail that makes it possible using some of the discarded options?

My idea for this application is to be a non-interactive app, and to be opened as child from the console app (cmd.exe/cscript.exe/etc.). And it watches parent process of been closed to close itself too.

This is what I have now:

```
using System.Threading;                     //Thread
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;       //DllImport

// A delegate type to be used as the handler routine for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

// An enumerated type for the control messages sent to the handler routine.
public enum CtrlTypes {
 CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
 CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
 CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
 CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
 CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
}

public class all {
    [DllImport("Kernel32")] public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();

/*
    //Maybe I will need GetConsoleWindow after.
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
*/

    private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType) {
        // Put your own handler here
        return true;
    }

    private void WaitThread(int mls) {
        Thread.Sleep(mls);
    }

    static void Main() {
        const uint ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x0ffffffff;
        Thread waitThread;
        //System.Console.WriteLine("!");
        //AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);
        
        while(true) {
            waitThread = new Thread(() => WaitThread(100));
            waitThread.Start();                    
            waitThread.Join();
        }
        
        // Next lines are ignored. I will close the process manually while it's in WIP(Work In Progress) phase.
        CloseApp();
    }

    static void CloseApp() {
        FreeConsole();
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

I found the "sleep routine" here: http://bresleveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/console-applicationdoevents-solved.html

I am getting errors:

> (49,29): error CS1525: El término de la expresión ')' no es válido
>
> (49,32): error CS1525: El término de la expresión '>' no es válido
>
> (49,34): error CS1026: Se esperaba ) (49,49): error CS1002: Se esperaba ;
>
> (49,49): error CS1525: El término de la expresión ')' no es válido

Line 49 is the first one inside the "while(true)".
I am new to C#, please consider this.

Comment: No, and your question is operating system specific.

Comment: If you start the process with the Process class, you can redirect teh IO to your Programm. You could then fake a console window and filter whatever you want from the user input. Otherwise I am not really sure what you want to do.

Comment: I have tried that option but I didn't find a way to redirect input in a proper way (asynchronous). Another problem I found is that a clear of the "screen" is not properly taken by the intercepter routine.

Comment: Please follow up your generic question with a specific example of what you're trying to do. At the least, I need to know if you're creating the external process and if so how. There are two ways to disable Ctrl+C in a child process, and you don't have to be attached to the console for either. You can pass the creation flag `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`; a new process group has Ctrl+C disabled by default. CMD's `start` command does this. You can also disable Ctrl+C in your process via `SetConsoleCtrlHandle(NULL, TRUE)`, and this will be inherited in the process parameters of the child.

Comment: Unfortunately the "fake console" approach often will not work. Many console applications do not simply read from and write to standard I/O using generic `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`. They use the console API (e.g. `ReadConsole`, `ReadConsoleInput`, `PeekConsoleInput`,  `WriteConsoleOutput`, etc) and fail hard if started without a console or with standard handles redirected to pipes or files.

Comment: If the child is non-interactive, it doesn't need a console (i.e. create a GUI app that simply creates no windows). In that case it doesn't matter whether Ctrl+C is disabled. But do you instead mean that you want the child to disable Ctrl+C in its parent?

Comment: Yes.. it's the parent's process the one that have to cancel ctrl+c...
well... not always the parent process... it's console.

I mean... cmd can open cmd and that second cmd can open my app.

Which one may I work on?

Comment: Sorry... first things first... forget that. I will investigate for that after first problem is solved. The process I have to cancel Ctrl+C is the parent one.

Comment: The flag that causes a process to ignore `CTRL_C_EVENT` is in its `ProcessParameters->ConsoleFlags` in its Process Environment Block (PEB). This is private to a process; there's no API to modify this from another process. The only point of control is when creating a child process, as I discussed above.

Comment: If you attach to the parent's console, you can disable processed-input mode to disable generating `CTRL_C_EVENT` for Ctrl+C, but unfortunately this also breaks normal handling of return in cooked reads. That's a deal breaker. That leaves attaching temporarily to call `GetConsoleWindow` to get the console window handle. Then you may be able to use other means to hook keyboard input to the window itself.

Comment: Can I create a new process group for a console app... from a non interactive one? If so... will the console app inherit the "Ctrl+C ignorer"?

Comment: That option you mentioned about attaching... does it require to be console app? a console app will be modal... so it willl avoid the parent process to work (for example: a batch script) while the child is running. Is it right?

Comment: There is no API to modify the `ProcessGroupId` or `ConsoleFlags` of an existing, external process. These are both private fields in its `ProcessParameters`. Also, it's the act of creating a new process group, at time of creation, that disables Ctrl+C handling in `ConsoleFlags`. It's not because the process is the lead process in a process group.

Comment: Ok. Then... setting a Ctrl Handler: discarded. Thanks for your help eryksun. Now I can investigate other options.

Comment: Attaching to the console has no effect on other processes attached to the console -- as long as you don't call console functions that block, such as a cooked read via `ReadConsole` or `ReadFile`. You can attach via `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`; call `GetConsoleWindow()` to get the window handle (if any; some consoles have no window, but that's not a problem here); and then `FreeConsole()` to detach.

Comment: My app isn't interactive so parent needs not to get IO from it. If i make my app a console one I can set a ctrl handler but that make it modal (so it doesn't work for me).

Comment: Being a console application is just a matter of the subsystem type set in the executable image header. For a console app, the init code in kernel32 / kernelbase allocates a console if one wasn't inherited from the parent. This subsystem type also affects some behaviors of the API with regard to implicitly inheriting standard handles and affects the runtime library init code and behavior, but none of that is relevant in your case. So you don't have to and should not build a console application. Just call `AttachConsole` and `FreeConsole` to temporarily attach to the console.

Comment: Ok... this goes to my bookmarks... I will start investigating about those methods tomorrow because it's too late in this side of the earth. Thanks for everything. Have a nice day.. week and beyond =)

Comment: I updated the question.
@eryksun can you have a look, please?

Comment: To send a control event, the console asks csrss.exe to create a thread that starts at the known `CtrlRoutine` function, with the event as the parameter. This function executes the registered control handlers until one returns true. Otherwise it calls the default handler that exits the process. `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` sets a control handler for the caller and only the caller. It has nothing to do with how other processes attached to the console will handle Ctrl+C, except that disabling Ctrl+C via the `NULL` handler gets inherited by child processes.

Comment: Ok... then I will try to replace SetConsoleCtrlHandler for Console.TreatCtrlCAsInput, but... what about the error inside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

If external console application is not the program you wrote, you can handle it through global keyboard hooking.

Comment: Thanks. That could be valid for me.
The routine have to check if the Window's class (it has to be "ConsoleWindowClass").

My exe will be launched from a console application so it has to check parent process but maybe that process is not the one who created the console window). If i open cmd inside cmd and then open my app... it could be wrong...

I think i may open another thread to question this.